# Laravel share data between few controllers

Tags: php, laravel

I have store site. And I would like to share betweend OrderController and PanelCotroller data with the last orderId from my Model Order. Here is my code:

```
class OrderController extends Controller
{
private $errors = [];

public function addOrder()
{

    if (!Auth::check()) {
        $this->errors[] = 'error';
        return redirect()->back()->with('errors', $this->errors);
    }

    $userId = Auth::id();

    $order = new Order();
    $isOrdered = $order->addOrder($userId, $this->cart);

    if ($isOrdered){
        return redirect('panel')->with('info', 'Everything fine');
    }

}

 }
```

Now my function addOrder return true or false. I can see orderId on OrderController when I call function getOrderId. But I want to call getOrderId in PanelController - mainSite action. When I create there object from Order, then my function getOrderId return me null...

```
class Order extends Model
{
protected $table = 'orders';
public $timestamps = false;
private $orderId;


public function addOrder($userId, Cart $cart)
{

    $order = new Order();
    $order->user_id = $userId;
    $order->save();

    foreach ($cart->getItems() as $cartProduct) {

        $orderProducts = new OrderProduct();
        $orderProducts->product_id = $cartProduct->getProduct()->id;
        $orderProducts->order_id = $order->id;
        $orderProducts->quantity = $cartProduct->getQuantity();
        $orderProducts->price = $cartProduct->getProduct()->price;
        $orderProducts->save();
    }

    $cart->clear();
    $this->orderId = $order->id;

    return true;

}


public function getOrderId()
{

    return $this->orderId;

}

}
```

And here is my PanelController.

class PanelController extends Controller
{

```
public function mainSite()
{

    if (Auth::check()) {

        $order = new Order();
        $order -> getOrderId() <---- here return me null instead my 
        last OrderId. 

        return View("panel");
    } else {
        return redirect('/login');
    }
}
```

How can I do to my my variable orderId or method getOrderId was visible to all controllers?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

After creating the order, add the id to you session. Then in the PanelController you can get the id from your session.

**OrderController:**

```
$order = new Order();
$isOrdered = $order->addOrder($userId, $this->cart);
session(['orderid' => $order->id]);
```

**PanelController:**

```
if (session()->has('orderid'))
    $order = Order::find(session('orderid'));
else
    dd('No order id found in session!');
```

Comment: Thx, this tip was very helpful.

Answer (score 2):

There are two ways you can obtain the value in other controllers -

1. Setting the value in a `BaseController` and extend it wherever you want.
2. Create a Session variable which will persist its value throughout multiple requests.

I will prefer the second method.